# How to enable the tab while clicking radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have got a task to do Jquery tab. On load the all tabs are disabled only the first tab is enabled also its radio button must be selected. If change the radio button then tab also have to change.
My page is

```
<script>
  $(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  $("#tabs").tabs("option", {
    "selected": 2,
    "disabled": [1,2,3]
});
    $( "input[type=submit], a, button" )
      .button()
      .click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });
      $('#enable1').click( function(){
      alert("a");
        $( "#tabs-2" ).tabs({ enabled: true });
      });
  });
  </script>

    <li><a href="#tabs-1">klj</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">jljl</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Sachin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Ganguly</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>jkljl</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>jkljl</p>
  </div>
   <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Sachin</p>
  </div>
   <div id="tabs-4">
    <p>Ganguly</p>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="radio" name="tabs-1" value="tabs-1">tabs-1
<input type="radio" name="tabs-2" value="tabs-2">tabs-2
<input type="radio" name="tabs-3" value="tabs-3">tabs-3
<input type="radio" name="tabs-4" value="tabs-4">tabs-4<br>
</body>
</html>
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your radio inputs id "enable";

```
<input type="radio" id="enable1" name="tabs-1" value="tabs-1">tabs-1
<input type="radio" name="tabs-2" id="enable2" value="tabs-2">tabs-2
<input type="radio" name="tabs-3" id="enable3" value="tabs-3">tabs-3
<input type="radio" name="tabs-4" id="enable4" value="tabs-4">tabs-4<br>
```

Also you should change enable and extend 
`$('#enable2').click( function(){
      alert("a");
              $( "#tabs" ).tabs('enable', 2);
      });`
to others.
It is better to handle it via one function and send the tabid to the function

Here's the live demo:
[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vnk8N/24/)

Comment: i add the live demo link too, take a look at it

Comment: I updated the code http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/4/ Here i used checkbox.When I click it will be displayed when i delete the selection it must disabled

Answer (score 1):

Live ID  here :-> http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/

Change you code to this

Radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="tabs" value="1">tabs-1
<input type="radio" name="tabs" value="2">tabs-2
<input type="radio" name="tabs" value="3">tabs-3
<input type="radio" name="tabs" value="4">tabs-4<br>
```

EDIT Have simplified the code further

```
 $(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
  $("#tabs").tabs("option", {
    "selected": 2,
    "disabled": [1,2,3]
  });
  $( "input[type=submit], a, button" )
      .button()
      .click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });  
 $( "input[type=radio]" ).click(function(){
     $('#tabs').tabs("enable", $(this).val());
     $('#tabs').tabs("select", $(this).val() );
});

}

 );
```

Comment: When I select another radio button, the early selected radio button is not cleared.

Comment: Ahh.. You need to keep the name same for all the radio buttons for it to be in the same group. Edited above and in the live link

Comment: Thats okay.By selecting new it doesn't show the new tab, it opens it only.

Comment: check this out please [http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/3/) . Am not sure what you mean?

Comment: I updated the code http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/4/
Here i used checkbox.When I click it will be displayed when i delete the selection it must disabled

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){

    var val = $(this).val();
   $("[href='#"+val+"']").parent().attr('class','ui-state-default ui-corner-top');
});
```

Comment: I updated the code http://jsfiddle.net/2aQ2g/4/ Here i used checkbox.When I click it will be displayed when i delete the selection it must disabled